# Lodash Remove all but one property from list of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there a lodash function that can produce the following:

Orignally:

```
var persons = [{"1":1, "2":2, "3":3}, {"1":12, "2":22, "3":32}];
var result = _.func(persons, "1")
```

After:

`result = [{"1":1},{"1":12}]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not as a single function.

You can combine [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs#map) to iterate through the array with [`_.pick()`](https://lodash.com/docs#pick) to reduce each object within it.

```
var result = _.map(persons, function (p) {
    return _.pick(p, '1');
});
```

You can also use [`_.partialRight()`](https://lodash.com/docs#partialRight) to create the iterator function:

```
var result = _.map(persons, _.partialRight(_.pick, '1'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [lodash - pick](https://lodash.com/docs#pick).

```
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b': '2', 'c': 3 };
_.pick(object, ['a', 'c']); // → { 'a': 1, 'c': 3 }
```